# TypeError: THREE.GLTFLoader is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, three.js, 3d, gltf

I'm trying to import a 3d model on my javascript file, this is the 'test.html' code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="module" src="./three.js-master/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="./three.js-master/build/three.js"></script>
        <script src="./test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the 'test.js' code:

```
var camera, scene, renderer;

window.onload = function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, 1.8, 0.1, 20.0 ); // fovy, aspect, near, far
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);
    renderer.setSize(1280, 720); //Size of the camera
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

    loader.load( 'duck/source/mindbreaker.glb', function ( gltf ) {

        scene.add( gltf.scene );

      }, undefined, function ( error ) {

        console.error( error );

      } );

    camera.position.x = 0.0;
    camera.position.y = 0.0;
    camera.position.z = 10.0;

    render();
}

function render(){
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

I run it on FIREFOX and I tried to change every possible path.
I also created a localhost to read the files, but the same error appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are loading in the ES6 version of GLTFLoader, but using the pre built (ES5) three.js.
Load in the ES5 version of the GLTFLoader from the `examples/js/loaders` folder (and load it after three.js).
eg.

```
<script src="./three.js-master/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="./three.js-master/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
<script src="./test.js"></script>
```